# Python print the dictionary according to the first element in the dictionary value descending order

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have a dict likes this:

```
mydict =  {
'Peter': [21, 2, 42.0], 
'Kate': [15, 3, 45.0],
'Tom': [16, 6, 96.0],
'Lucy': [28, 4, 112.0],
 }
```

The key is string,value is list.
I want to print mydict according to the first element in the dictionary value descending order.

For example, I want this output：

```
 'Lucy',28,4,112.0
 'Peter',21,2,42.0
 'Tom',16,6,96.0
 'Kate',15,3,45.0
```

How can I output such a result？

Comment: Can you demonstrate *any* effort at solving this yourself?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can iterate over the sorted result of `dict.items`, and use `str.join`:

```
mydict = {
'Lucy': [28, 4, 112.0], 
'Peter': [21, 2, 42.0], 
'Kate': [15, 3, 45.0], 
'Tom': [16, 6, 96.0]}
for a, b in sorted(mydict.items(), key=lambda x:x[-1][0] if isinstance(x, list) else x, reverse = True):
  print('{},{}'.format(a, ','.join(map(str, b)) if isinstance(b, list) else b))
```

Output:

```
Lucy,28,4,112.0
Peter,21,2,42.0
Tom,16,6,96.0
Kate,15,3,45.0
```

Comment: Sir,I use my real data,I changed mydict  to real data.There was a mistake:    for a, b in sorted(mydict .items(), key=lambda x:x[-1][0], reverse = True):
TypeError: 'int' object is not subscriptable

Comment: @Rhaegal What does your real data look like?

Comment: @Rhaegal The data looks the same. Does the code work for you with the original input, `{'Lucy': [28, 4, 112.0], 'Peter': [21, 2, 42.0], 'Kate': [15, 3, 45.0], 'Tom': [16, 6, 96.0]}`?

Comment: @Rhaegal It seems that there are some values in the dictionary that are integers, not lists. Please see my recent edit, as I added checks to handle those occurrences.

Comment: Sir,I use your latest code to test,but the order of the result is disorderly

Comment: @Rhaegal the `print` function should be passed: `'{},{}'.format(a, ','.join(map(str, b)) if isinstance(b, list) else b)`. Please try the code from my most recent edit.

Comment: Sir,I used your most recent"for a, b in sorted(mydict.items(), key=lambda x:x[-1][0] if isinstance(x, list) else x, reverse = True):
  print('{},{}'.format(a, ','.join(map(str, b)) if isinstance(b, list) else b))"But the result is no sorted.

Comment: @Rhaegal What specifically is not sorted?

Comment: The result is 4 columns, and should be descended according to the second column.The result  now is in my picture.